# Animate the addition/deletion of UICollectionViewCells

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My problem: Find a way, such that when a button is pressed a new colleciton view cell is inserted by an animation of it sliding in from the right side of the screen.

As of right now, I have a button in my view, when it is clicked, adds a new object to my model, then calls reloadData and the new cells just appears on the screen. All I am struggling with is the animation. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want the cells to animate, you could set a property `shouldAnimate = YES`. 
Then in your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` check that property and apply the animation if needed (or remove it).

After setting the property, reload only the visibleCells: `[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems]`.

Now, since the animation is provided when a cell is requested through the Datasource-Protocol, you also get the animation when you scroll.